# 2 SQL Databases with crucial data

Tags: sql

I have two databases with 45gb each with very crucial data. Now the sql is telling me that both are corrupted. My database is in emergency mode.  What I can do to put it back online?
And when  I try to attach the database on another server  it says that the LOG FILE DONT EXISTS.  When  I try to copy or rename the Windows says that it is corrupted.
Is there any way to repair?

I have run some sql commands that I found on the internet but nothing is fixing the problem.

Comment: Stop what you're doing immediately. Shut down the server, send the hard drives to a professional data recovery service. If you're lucky, you may get some of your data back. Be prepared to pay lots of money for this service.

Comment: Also: take a serious look at your backup situation.

Comment: Restore from backup?

Comment: Backup was not configured somehow. The last one was in 2016. I need all the data before the last date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To change database:

**alter database set online with no_wait**

This query changes the database from  if you want to check database

*use dbname
go
dbcc checkdb with all_errormsgs*

I am sure that your db is not corrupted. If it is corrupted it will not attach, but sql server gives you a error that ldf file is missing.
But in a pinch if it is not and the base is damaged, you can use the program [MDF Repair Kit](http://www.mdf.repair/) to try to do mdf repair file.

Hope this information will be helpful for you.

Comment: Thank you all for your advice! I'm appreciative for your responses and help.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @EEAA. If you have no expertise in troubleshooting / recovering corrupted SQL databases, it is better to contact your local MSRP to get this solved ASAP.